# Elfsight Slider on Pagination Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

Can the elfsight carousel slider widget https://elfsight.com/slider-widget/ be triggered when the pagination is hovered? Can't find any documentation on this.

The goal is to go to the specific slide of the hovered pagination as well as change the the "visited" slide text to a different color.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to this issue:

```
$('.eapp-slider-slider-pagination-dot').hover(function() {
    $( this ).trigger( "click" );
});
```

The above code will trigger the slider based on the hovered pagination.